# PhoneGap integration

Tags: cordova

I have a native app in Objective C for the iPhone. Can I integrate Phonegap to my existing native application?

Is there any option to convert my existing iPhone code to phonegap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Phonegap requires HTML5, CSS and JavaScript in order for it to compile into a working application package.

It's definitely not backwards compatible with Objective C. You can however create a plugin for added functionality using Objective-c which can be used alongside the HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Comment: Why -1 this ? It's an honest answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to convert a native application to a PhoneGap application, BUT it is definitely possible to integrate PhoneGap into a native application. I was asking this question about a year ago and found this link:

https://web.archive.org/web/20120506173552/https://phonegap.com/2010/04/21/introducing-iphone-cleavage/

This link shows how you can go about integrating PhoneGap into a native application. The code presented here is a bit old and is based on a fairly old verion of PhoneGap (version 0.9.5, I believe), but it will work up until version 1.0.0.RC2. Version 1.1.0 of PhoneGap, made some breaking changes with regard to this code, so it would have to be updated to work with version 1.1.0 and higher. I know this because I have just finished updating my integration of PhoneGap to work with the latest version (1.4.1).

I have also read that the latest version of PhoneGap includes functionality for integrating into a native application by making use of PGViewController. Install the latest version of PhoneGap and then read the document "How to use PhoneGap as a component.pdf". This functionality has now been code named "Cleaver" (somewhat more professional sounding than "Cleavage"! haha)

So, bottom line... yes, you can integrate PhoneGap into an Objective-C application. In fact, I even have PhoneGap integrated into a native application written in MonoTouch and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with Cordova 1.4, you can integrate Cordova as a component in your iOS applications

See: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS